# Normalization constant of the Vacuum polarization

Tags: quantum-field-theory, integration

In the article [*"On gauge invariance and vacuum polarization"*](http://isites.harvard.edu/fs/docs/icb.topic1088750.files/Schwinger-SPT.pdf) by Schwinger, at some point the equation

$$\frac{C}{s^2}\int e^{i\frac{x^2}{4s}} \, dx =1$$

is said to have the solution

$$C=-\frac{i}{(4\pi)^2}$$

However, if

$$\int e^{-a x^2} \, dx = \sqrt{\frac{\pi}{a}}$$

then the first integral is solved by using $a=-i/(4s)$, which gives

$$\int e^{i \frac{x^2}{4s}} \, dx = \sqrt{4\pi s i}$$

so the first equation should have instead the solution

$$C = \sqrt{\frac{-i s^3}{4\pi}}$$

Clearly I'm missing something but I don't understand what.

Comment: Check what the integration path is.